# Конвертирование видео в формат пригодный для стриминга с помощью MP4Box

Tags: видео, mp4, dash

Пытаюсь обработать видео с расширением `.mp4` в формат пригодный для стриминга с помощью `MP4Box`, но безуспешно.

Конвертацию делаю с помощью такой команды:

`MP4Box -dash 1000 \'{currentPath}\' -out \'{destinationPath}\'`

в итоге получаю два файла:

1. `{currentPath}_dashinit.mp4`
2. `{destinationPath}.mpd`

Второй файл - это какой-то `xml` файл манифеста.
Первый - какоето итоговое видео, но оно не стримится.

Под стримом я имею ввиду потоковое воспроизведение в плере.

Подскажите, кто сталкивался, как его правильно обработать..